# Démodé, é proparoxítona ou oxítona?

Tags: gramática

Alguns dicionários admitem a grafia da palavra francesa, **Démodé**, escrita assim, com acentuação aguda na primeira e última sílaba.

Nesse cenário qual é a precedência de avaliação para determinar a classe de sílaba tônica para essa palavra?

Notei que é comum a grafia com acento circunflexo na última sílaba, **Demodê**, neste caso claramente seria uma oxítona valendo-se da indicação por acentuação.

Abaixo os links de alguns dicionários que admitem essa grafia:

https://dicionario.priberam.org/d%C3%A9mod%C3%A9

https://www.dicio.com.br/demode/

Comment: Interessante, o francês não tem sílaba tônica. Em português, porém, falamos como se fosse oxítona. Então, diria que *démodé* é originalmente átona, mas aportuguesada oxítona.

Comment: @Schilive não entendo nada de francês, no entanto a pronúncia parece átona sim, porém, a inclinação para a acentuação com circunflexo na última sílaba faz mais sentido como admitido em outros dicionários como o Michaelis por exemplo.

Comment: O acento agudo em "é" no francês não indica tonicidade, mas que a letra é pronunciada /e/ (o som de "ê" no português) em vez do valor padrão /ɵ/ (uma vogal central). Por isso ao aportuguesar a palavra esses acentos devem ser ignorados. De forma similar, a palavra francesa "écran" tornou-se "ecrã", que alguns escrevem incorretamente "écrã".

Comment: Muito interessante. Então quando se ver alguma palavra escrita com mais de uma acentuação tônica podemos ignorar, sendo assim prevalece da sílaba mais próxima do fim?

Comment: @AloisoJunior Não necessariamente. A presença de dois acentos agudos indica que a grafia é estrangeira, logo é preciso saber em que língua a palavra está escrita para pronunciá-la corretamente.

Comment: É difícil generalizar; “ímã” é uma palavra nativa com dois acentos diacríticos, e a sílaba tônica é a primeira, embora o til em outras palavras (confronte _falaram_ e _falarão_) traga para si a sílaba tônica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É oxítona. Infelizmente, não há como estabelecer uma regra para determinar a sílaba tônica de uma palavra se ela usa uma grafia estrangeira, como é o caso de “démodé.” Neste caso, a melhor aposta é procurar variantes com a grafia aportuguesada — a variante “demodê” que você encontrou registrada — e determinar a sílaba tônica com base nesta grafia.

Talvez convenha relembrar que as palavras estrangeiras, quando são adotadas por línguas em geral e pelo português em específico, tendem a manter a sua pronúncia tanto quanto possível. Como as palavras francesas são, em sua esmagadora maioria, oxítonas (*pace* o comentário de Schilive), é quase certo que qualquer palavra tomada do francês seja oxítona, e sua grafia adaptada refletirá essa realidade.